# Jquery dropdown list with own div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can i make such thing as here: [link](http://www.autoklad.ua/)

Now i done this so (rails haml):

```
= link_to "Масла/автохимия", :oil_mp, :id => "oil-dd"
          .oil-dd
            %ul
              %li
                = link_to "Масла моторные для легковых автомобилей", oils_path(:product_type_id => 13)
              %li
                = link_to "Масла трансмисионные", oils_path(:product_type_id => 15)
              %li
                = link_to "Антифризы", oils_path(:product_type_id => 3)
              %li
                = link_to "Вода дисцилированная", oils_path(:product_type_id => 6)
```

And my jquery code look's so:

```
$("#oil-dd").mouseover(function() {
    $(".oil-dd").show();
  });
  $("#oil-dd").mouseout(function() {
    $(".oil-dd").fadeOut(2000);
  });
```

My main trouble is that my div with ul, which appears ("`.oil-dd`") get's dissapear, when i'm out of #oil-dd area... But how to do, that .oil-dd still is on page, even if i'm out of #oil-dd (it must show if i on .oil-dd or #oil-dd), but .oil-dd hide when i'm out of .oil-dd and #oil-dd ?

It must be as on linked page (near `Автозапчасти`)

in html

```
<a href="/catalogs/oil_mp" id="oil-dd">Масла/автохимия</a>
    <div class="oil-dd" style="display: block;">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=13">Масла моторные для легковых автомобилей</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=15">Масла трансмисионные</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=3">Антифризы</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=6">Вода дисцилированная</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=5">Моющие жидкости</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=8">Жидкости тормозные</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=18">Автокосметика/автохимия</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=7">Жидкости гидравлические</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=11">Масла прочие</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=10">Масла индустриальные</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=12">Масла для грузовых автомобилей</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=16">Смазки</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/catalogs/oils?product_type_id=17">Тех.жидкости</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

Comment: did you mean this? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59666091/jqq.jpg

Comment: What is the ID/class name for the `<div>` containing the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    var timeOut=0;
    $("#oil-dd").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        $(".oil-dd").stop(1,1).show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
            $(".oil-dd").fadeOut(1000);
        }, 1000);

    });


    $(".oil-dd").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
            $(".oil-dd").fadeOut(1000);
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

[**An Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKFTf/1/).

Comment: is good.... but have bug's: it didn't dessapear when i go to other .class, it still there... but if mouse is only on #id all is ok

Comment: @PavelBY, you didn't provide any `html` code so it's a sample only to give you an idea.

Comment: hm, what the difference between edition before? Main trouble was that in some cases (i have not one such element, but many (with own classes and id, but schema is analog)) it doesn't dessapear

Comment: for example if i add analog of this, with other class and id, when mouse is in ul/li of first and then i quick send mouse to second element id (head of ul li, or Масла/автохимия in this case) then list didn't dessapear... Try to add some more header links... with the same sub's